# Pass Connection Pool Object to Method

Tags: java, connection-pooling

I need to pass the connection pool object into a ScheduledExecutorService thread but I am having difficulties doing so.  I attempted to add final in front of the declaration but that throws the following error...    The final local variable connection cannot be assigned. It must be blank and not using a compound assignment

How can properly pass this connection object?

```
public class AdminManager extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable tableQueue;
    private JTable tableFilled;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    AdminManager frame = new AdminManager();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        BoneCP connectionPool = null;
        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            // load the database driver (make sure this is in your classpath!)
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        try {
            // setup the connection pool
            BoneCPConfig config = new BoneCPConfig();
            config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://192.0.0.1:3306/db"); // jdbc url specific to your database, eg jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/yourdb
            config.setUsername("root"); 
            config.setPassword("");
            connectionPool = new BoneCP(config); // setup the connection pool

            connection = connectionPool.getConnection(); // fetch a connection

            if (connection != null){
                System.out.println("Connection successful!");
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }        
ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                System.out.println("Working ... ");
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM table;";
                Statement st;
                try {
                    st = connection.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }, 2000, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a dummy reference that is only used inside the executor:

```
final Connection conn = connection;

ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            System.out.println("Working ... ");
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM table;";
            Statement st;
            try {
                st = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }
    }, 2000, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

If the issue cannot be solved this way (can't see the rest of your code), you could define an external task class to hold the code:

```
class ThreadTask implements Runnable {
     private Connection connection;

     public ThreadTask(Connection c) {
          connection = c;
     }

     @Override
     public void run() {
        System.out.println("Working ... ");
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM table;";
        Statement st;
        try {
            st = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

And:

```
ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ThreadTask(connection));
```

Comment: But that creates a new class?  I changed my code up to match what you suggested and it gives me  No enclosing instance of type AdminManager is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type AdminManager (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of AdminManager).

Comment: @scriptdiddy: Try to make the class `static` or move it outside the current class where you are working.

Comment: @scriptdiddy: Have you tried to apply the first solution before creating the new class? From your updated code it should work without defining a new class. Just define a final reference to the same connection object.

Comment: Yes it didn't work.  I updated my code above so you can see the bigger picture.  I created a new class, like you suggested and it seems to work execute but says the connection is close java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed!

Comment: @scriptdiddy: Are you sure the connection cannot be closed by the time you reach the executor code?

Comment: ^ woops.  Sorry I forgot about the "finally" part of my try catch block.  Thank you very much for your help.  It seems to be working now!!!